# Importing a plain-text file using HTML5 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, import, local-storage, filereader

I'm new to JavaScript, so forgive me if the answer to this question is an obvious one.

I'm trying to set up an import function for a text-editor web-application.

My code is as follows:

```
function dataImport() {
    confirm("Are you sure you want to import the selected file? This will overwrite any data that is currently saved in the application workplace.");
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    window.localStorage.setItem("AppData", fileReader.readAsText(document.querySelector("#import-selector").value));
};
```

And it should be activated by:

```
<input id="import-selector" type="file" /><button id="import-button" onclick="dataImport();">Import File</button>
```

Instead of writing the contents of the file to the localStorage, however, it merely writes the word 'undefined'. I take it some kind of error has happened, but I'm not sure what it is.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: Google Chrome, the dev channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard of a `lick` event in HTML. Maybe it's something new to HTML5 ;)

Try changing your `onlick="...` trigger to `onclick="...`

Maybe that will work?

---

Now that that's fixed, try this example: [Chrome FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100927/chrome-filereader)

I tried it, and it works *flawlessly*. It outputs the file contents into the error console.

Good luck!

Comment: Woah, that was stupid of me. Now I'm finally getting an error in the console! I've corrected the question to suit.

Comment: Hmm. I've repurposed the script you mentioned but I get this error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".
I've put the customized script online here: http://jsfiddle.net/CwfSy/

Comment: Nevermind. For some reason it didn't like me having the script execute onclick, but when I set the input tag to do it onchange it worked.