# Reading a file in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to write a java script to read a file in chrome and I am using the javascript debugger of chrome. 
here is the script:

```
function myFunction()
{
alert("I am an alert box!");
var e ;
var contents;
var control = document.getElementById("myfile");
  files = control.files;
console.log("Filename: " + files[0].name);
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(files[0]);

reader.onload = function (e) { 


    contents = e.target.result;

    };

console.log("File contents: " + contents);
console.log("I am an alert box!");console.log("I am an alert box!");



}





</script>
```

when i run the code the contents variable is undefined. Plenty of discussion has gone into this but i have not found a solution. I am using the --allow-file-acess-from-files option.
Now the following code works in a strange manner:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
alert("I am an alert box!");
var e ;
var contents;
var control = document.getElementById("myfile");
  files = control.files;
console.log("Filename: " + files[0].name);
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(files[0]);

reader.onload = function (e) {
    contents = e.target.result ;
    };
console.log(e.target.result);
console.log("I am an alert box!");console.log("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
```

It throws an error which is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined"
However in the watch expression window the following variables show that the file is being read.

event.target.result: "firmware file
↵:10000000782600204D4B0000B94B0000B94B000092
↵:10001000B94B0000B94B0000B94B000000000000D4
↵:10002000000000000000000000000000B94B0000CC
↵:10003000B94B000000000000B94B0000210B00008C
↵:10004000B94B0000B94B0000B94B0000B94B0000A0
↵:10005000B94B0000B94B0000B94B0000B94B000090
↵:10006000B94B0000B94B0000B94B0000B94B000080
↵:10007000B94B0000B94B0000B94B0000B94B000070
↵:10008000B94B0000B94B0000B94B0000B94B000060
and the same ouput for e.target.result and contents variable.

Why is the code behaviour is so wierd?
Kindly help me out. I am not very skilled with javascripting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome FileReader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100927/chrome-filereader)

Answer (score 1):

`e.target` will be undefined on your 2nd console.log there towards the bottom - only one is inside your `onload` function, and therefore has `e` set.

The second one is acting on the `var e ;` you defined at the top, which is null, and therefore `e.target.result` is invalid.

e: in other words, delete this line, or move it into the function:

[image: bogus line]

Comment: after I do the changes you told me to, and when I step through the code, it never enters the onload function. Hence I put the statement there so that it atleast enters the onload function.