# Upload file inside chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to add a browse button inside my Chrome extension. Users click it and choose a file. I then want to retrieve the file contents (bytes) and do some work on it.

I don't want to have to submit the file to a remote server and then get the response (if that's even doable from inside a Chrome extension), it should be all client-side.

Is this doable inside Chrome extensions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be looking at the [`FileReader` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

> The `FileReader` object lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer, using `File` or `Blob` objects to specify the file or data to read.

A very good basic example of using this interface is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100927/chrome-filereader).

A minimal example: suppose that you have an `<input type="file" id="file">` with a text file selected.

```
var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e){
  console.log(e.target.result);
}
reader.readAsText(file);
```

If you need methods other than reading as text (i.e. binary data), see the docs.

Also, this is a good overview: [Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)

Comment: I'm following this exactly, but I can't get onload to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question it is totally feasible to load and process a file within an extension. I implemented it using message passing https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/.

Here is an example of how you can implement it, in my case I used the input file to load an excel. This is my public repo.
https://github.com/juanmachuca95/gomeetplus

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33339255)