# Chrome Extension: Allow user to add files and store them

Tags: javascript, html, video, google-chrome-extension, storage

I am coding an extension that replaces the default *New Tab* for a simple HTML file that has a video playing in the background.

I would like to let the user input more videos. This means, that the extension has to be able to open some kind of a file explorer and store the selected file so that it can later be played.

Thanks

Comment: I remember this question was asked multiple times so there should be an answer so look for it. In short you would use a normal file input, read the data into a base64 data URI, store it in the extension storage and use as is in the src attribute.

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886628/upload-file-inside-chrome-extension