# JavaScript Click does not work on Google translate image

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, click, jquery-selectors

I try to code JavaScript extension for translate an image which is in the windows clipboard.
Site page web: `https://translate.google.fr/?hl=fr&sl=auto&tl=fr&op=images`

An image is already in the clipboard.
When I execute the code JavaScript on console:

```
document.querySelector('[aria-label="Coller une image depuis le presse-papiers"]').click();
```

the button is found by JavaScript selector and click is done but a message says

> impossible de coller le contenu du presse-papiers pour le moment. Ressayer de copier l'image" = "impossible to paste clipboard content at this time. Retry to copy the image"

If I click with the mouse on the button in the web page, it works...
Why? How to do with JavaScript?

Help please / Thanks

Comment: probably security feature in browser to ensure user wants access to clipboard.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you do it like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent#javascript

Comment: I 've tried the code for simulate click : same result the google page show the same message

function simulateClick() {
const cb = document.querySelector("#yDmH0d > c-wiz > div > div.ToWKne > c-wiz > div.caTGn > c-wiz > div.iggndc > c-wiz > div > div > div > div.rlWbvd > div.gLXQIf > div.T12pLd > div:nth-child(2) > div > button")

  // Create a synthetic click MouseEvent
  let evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window,
  });

  // Send the event to the checkbox element
  cb.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
simulateClick();

Comment: And which security feature about the clipboard : when real click with mouse on the button, the picture is get from the windows clipboard by the javascript page

Answer (score 1):

**Check if the following steps are done:**

1. Do you close the `DevTools` in the tab of Google Translate web page?
2. Do Chrome focus on the tab of Google Translate when you execute click event?

---

**Possible cause**

This might be caused by the secure limit of `navigator.clipboard API`. According to the solution of: [DOMException on calling navigator.clipboard.readText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56306153/domexception-on-calling-navigator-clipboard-readtext), you have to ensure you are focus on the page view of Google Translate.

However, if you open the `DevTools`, Chrome detects that you **don't** focus on the page view.

**How to focus page by Chrome Extensions API**

To [focus on the window](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-update):

```js
chrome.windows.update(
  windowId,
  { focused: true }
);
```

To [focus on the tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-update):

```js
chrome.tabs.update(
  tabId,
  { active: true }
);
```

---

Here is a demo of auto pasting: [Auto Paste Picture to Google Translate](https://github.com/LyreneLiu/auto-paste-picture-to-google-translate)

Comment: Hello Liu. Thanks for response but the sample Auto-Paste-Picture-In-Google-Translate does not work. After download, and modify label, when add extension, the google translate image page is opened and activated. I open in new tab a sample image web page https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z13uApmlL._AC_UF894,1000_QL80_.jpg and i copy it in clipboard (ctrl-c or click copy) but nothing happens ?

Comment: @OliveLion I saw your issue in the Github repository. I guess that adding alert will cause the page unfocused. Is it still nothing happened if you remove the alert?

Comment: @Liu : i add the alert because nothing happens. So without the alert it does not work too ...

Comment: @Liu. 
I modify my code to force Chrome focus on the tab of Google Translate when I execute click event. But this not solve the problem. 

At launch, because i need it, my extension is opened in a new window. 
Now, i see that else if the active tab in the main chrome window is set on google translate, the active window is the extension popup. How to set focus and activate the main chrome window ?

Comment: @Liu

Have you got a code sample for set the focus on the main window ? From background.js of the extension opened in a dedicated window, how to set the main window activate where is the tab of the google translate web page ?

Before creating popup extension window, i try 
var mainWin = chromes.windows.getCurrent();
and after in a onmessage listener function i try mainWin.focus();
but it does not work ...

Comment: @OliveLion I updated the post and the Github repository. Could you give it a try?

Comment: @Liu
Thanks a lot for help. I try the new version but it does not work. When i open an image web page and press CTRL+C, the extension open a new active window with the google translate. But nothing happens after (I have well modified the label parameter in config.js with fr label version). So, if I click manually on the button the translation is done. 
In extensions page, i have an error on the extension : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click') for line document.querySelector(`[aria-label="${config.custom.btnAriaLabel}"]`).click();

Comment: @Liu  to force click, i modify code of the pastePic function with document.querySelector("#yDmH0d > c-wiz > div > div.ToWKne > c-wiz > div.caTGn > c-wiz > div.iggndc > c-wiz > div > div > div > div.rlWbvd > div.gLXQIf > div.T12pLd > div:nth-child(2) > div > button").click();  .... then the click is well done but i have the famous message "impossible de coller le contenu du presse-papiers pour le moment. Ressayer de copier l'image" = "impossible to paste clipboard content at this time. Retry to copy the image" and the translation is not launched ... and if i click manually it's ok

Comment: @Liou : my need for this extension is to go to a local url (http://127.0.0.1/url that is a python service which copy image to clipboard), and after open this url waiting for objectf dom div with id="COPY DONE OK" to automatically open google translate image web page, click on the translate button, wait to translate, dowload translated picture and check if translate picture is downloaded, and return on locally url waiting another done copy ...

Comment: @Liu : in your config.js i have modify this ... >>>   btnAriaLabel: 'Coller une image depuis le presse-papiers'    >>> this is the french label of the aria-label
++ 
And if i clean errors and refresh the extension, at many times, the worker is in state "service worker (Inactive) "

Comment: In the case of my extension, do you reload the picture page after reloading the extension? That force to inject the content.js.

Comment: @Liou : for my need this is not the copy event wich work only with CTRL-C on a web page, but an event wich can detect when dom div object exists on web page ... so i need first to go to a local url, and when div exists to switch on google translate to process, and to loop to the local url waiting for new cycle; Thanks a lot for your help .. I have thousands of images to convert

Comment: @Liu > Yes :-) In the case of your extension, I reload the picture page after reloading the extension because esle no new google translate page is opened. I see than when refresh the inactive worked state change to active :-)

Comment: In your case, do you do JavaScript `navigator.clipboard.write()` to put the content in the API? Google Translate will get the image by `navigator.clipboard.read()`.

Comment: @Liu : no, I use python code for : 1/ create simple local webserver with code like here https://pythonbasics.org/webserver/    .... and 2/ inside the server code get new image an copy it to windows clipboard with code like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322132/copy-image-to-clipboard  . So for the extension the steps need : to call the local web page, waiting div label KO, and go to google translate image for click in the good button to get clipboard content, and after click on download button to get translated picture and control that download is ok to renew loop ...

Comment: `navigator.clipboard` supports Windows clipboard. So if my extension is worked, you can  just call `async function init() { await getConfig(); chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async function (msg, sender, sendResponse) { if (msg === config.msgs.transPageActive) pastePic(); }); chrome.runtime.sendMessage(config.msgs.tabInit); }` and after you copy the image and call extension to do `await retrieveTranslateTab(); await focusTranslateTab(msg);` .

Comment: @Liu : thanks / can you update you extension code to do that ? i am beginner in chrome extension dev

Comment: @Liu : another idea without local webserver and wihtout clipboard copy/paste is to get files in local PC. Google translate accept upload file (but with selection box for each file) / i see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886628/upload-file-inside-chrome-extension  that chrome extension can get local file and upload it. It will be possible to simulate upload ? what do you think about it ?   It will super if extension can be useful for many peoples

Comment: @OliveLion I think it's harder to simulate upload because the behavior of the button type `file` and the `drag-and-drop` listener are fixed. Back to the original problem, I think trying to set focus on the window and the tab of Google Translate will work. And the core code I've updated in the post.

Comment: @OliveLion There are other possibilities of image accessed failed. (1) The image url begins with `data:` (base64 source). (2) The image url is in sandbox mode in which JavaScript was blocked. (3) The image isn't included in targets of `Ctrl+C` detected by browser.

Comment: @Liu : hello Liu. I have download last code of you extension. When i copy an image on brower, your extension automatically open a new widow with google translate web page, and automatically clic on button from convert to clipboard. but the same message : impossible de coller le contenu du presse-papiers pour le moment. Ressayer de copier l'image" = "impossible to paste clipboard content at this time. Retry to copy the image"

Comment: @Liu : hello, have you been able to make any progress in the extension code to be able to translate from an image? Thank you