# Use GoogleMaps API from coordinates in a csv file in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, csv, google-maps-api-3

To be honest, I am not very familiar with JavaScript. But now I really need to use it to map a set of coordinates stored in my csv file, so I'll need JavaScript and GoogleMaps API.

The data I have in my csv is like this.

```
latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2, latitude3, longitude3, so on.
latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2, latitude3, longitude3, so on.
latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2, latitude3, longitude3, so on.
.......... so on.
```

Where each line represents a route and latitude-x and longitude-x represent a location. I hope you get my point.

I kind of mixed the code I got from w3school, google official site, stackoverflow and many others, then I modified it. And what I got so far is the following.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script
 src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
 </script>

 
</head>

<body>

 <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
 <div id="googleMap" style="width:800px;height:580px;"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
 
 var coordinates = [];
 
 document.getElementById('file').onload = function(){

 var file = this.files[0];

   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onchange = function(progressEvent){
     // Entire file
     //console.log(this.result);


     var lines = this.result.split('\n');

     for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
      
      var point = this.result.split(',');

      var count =0;

      for(var dua=0; dua<point.length; dua++){
       if(dua%2==0){
        var latitude = point[dua];
       }else{
        var longitude = point[dua];
        coordinates[count] = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude+","+longitude);
        console.log(coordinates[count]);
        count++;
       }
      }

     }
   };
  reader.readAsText(file);
 };


  function getCoor(){
   return coordinates;
  }
  
  function initialize(){
   var mapProp = {

     center:new google.maps.LatLng(8.611911,41.146056),
     zoom:6,
     mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
     
   var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);


   var myTrip = [];
   var coordinates = getCoor();
   for(var c=0; c<coordinates.length; c++){
    myTrip += coordinates[c];
   }

   
   //console.log(myTrip);
   var flightPath=new google.maps.Polyline({
     path:myTrip,
     strokeColor:"#0000FF",
     strokeOpacity:0.8,
     strokeWeight:8
   });

   flightPath.setMap(map);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I store the coordinates I got per line from my csv file to array coordinate[count]. Now I want every line of coordinate to be passed to the initialize() function so it can be processed through the API. But I am confused at this point, especially seeing how the file is read through its own function, and I can't pass it out. I hope you get what I mean, just drop a comment if you don't understand something. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the file reader code from the answer to [Chrome FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100927/chrome-filereader)

1. you need to wait for the DOM to be rendered before searching it for elements (move anything using document.getElementById inside the initialize function).
2. You have issues with your code for processing the file contents, for one `coordinates[count] = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude+","+longitude);` is not valid, the google.maps.LatLng takes two numbers as arguments, not a comma separated string.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdugymah/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function getCoor() {
  return coordinates;
}

function handle_files(files) {
  for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    file = files[i];
    console.log(file);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    ret = [];
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      console.log(e.target.result);
      var lines = e.target.result.split('\n');
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {

        var point = lines[line].split(',');

        var count = 0;
        var coordinates = [];
        for (var dua = 0; dua < point.length; dua++) {
          if (dua % 2 == 0) {
            var latitude = point[dua];
          } else {
            var longitude = point[dua];
            coordinates[count] = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            console.log(coordinates[count]);
            count++;
          }
        }
        var myTrip = [];
        for (var c = 0; c < coordinates.length; c++) {
          myTrip.push(coordinates[c]);
          bounds.extend(coordinates[c]);
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        //console.log(myTrip);
        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: myTrip,
          strokeColor: "#0000FF",
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 8
        });

        flightPath.setMap(map);

      }

    }
    reader.onerror = function(stuff) {
      console.log("error", stuff);
      console.log(stuff.getMessage());
    }
    reader.readAsText(file); //readAsdataURL
  }

}

function initialize() {

  var mapProp = {

    center: new google.maps.LatLng(8.611911, 41.146056),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="handle_files(this.files)" />
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```

Test file contents with 2 entries:

```
40.712940,-74.007120,40.713080,-74.007220,40.713080,-74.007220,40.713810,-74.008820,40.713810,-74.008820,40.714360,-74.008380,40.714930,-74.007940,40.715440,-74.007540,40.716010,-74.007110,40.716540,-74.006680,40.717080,-74.006250,40.717680,-74.005770,40.718300,-74.005380,40.718300,-74.005380,40.718410,-74.005330,40.718630,-74.005240,40.718640,-74.005240,40.718670,-74.005220,40.718680,-74.005220,40.718690,-74.005220,40.718720,-74.005220,40.718850,-74.005190,40.719020,-74.005180,40.719400,-74.005180,40.719860,-74.005210,40.720630,-74.005210,40.720700,-74.005230,40.721040,-74.005260,40.721710,-74.005320,40.721830,-74.005350,40.721960,-74.005370,40.722070,-74.005400,40.722120,-74.005400,40.722160,-74.005400,40.722230,-74.005380,40.723010,-74.005070,40.723630,-74.004810,40.723630,-74.004810,40.723720,-74.005610,40.723750,-74.005900,40.723810,-74.006080,40.723830,-74.006150,40.723850,-74.006270,40.723870,-74.006360,40.723890,-74.006420,40.723910,-74.006470,40.723940,-74.006530,40.723970,-74.006600,40.724000,-74.006640,40.724070,-74.006740,40.724150,-74.006840,40.724210,-74.006900,40.724270,-74.006940,40.724300,-74.006970,40.724320,-74.006980,40.724350,-74.006990,40.724360,-74.006990,40.724380,-74.007000,40.724390,-74.007000,40.724400,-74.007000,40.724460,-74.006990,40.724510,-74.006990,40.724630,-74.007010,40.724630,-74.007010,40.724850,-74.006990,40.724920,-74.006980,40.725000,-74.006970,40.725120,-74.006970,40.725240,-74.007010,40.725330,-74.007060,40.725430,-74.007150,40.725510,-74.007230,40.725610,-74.007330,40.725690,-74.007460,40.725760,-74.007590,40.725810,-74.007730,40.725860,-74.007880,40.725900,-74.008020,40.725930,-74.008180,40.725950,-74.008340,40.726260,-74.011430,40.726300,-74.011640,40.726340,-74.011870,40.726370,-74.012150,40.726500,-74.013540,40.726640,-74.014940,40.726680,-74.015320,40.726720,-74.015620,40.727500,-74.020640,40.727580,-74.021110,40.727650,-74.021580,40.728380,-74.026090,40.728440,-74.026490,40.728500,-74.026920,40.728500,-74.026930,40.728870,-74.031050,40.728930,-74.031380,40.729020,-74.031750,40.729060,-74.031870,40.729110,-74.032100,40.729230,-74.032470,40.729370,-74.033000,40.729410,-74.033140,40.729410,-74.033150,40.729640,-74.033960,40.729650,-74.033980,40.729790,-74.034510,40.729800,-74.034520,40.729800,-74.034530,40.729860,-74.034750,40.729860,-74.034760,40.729870,-74.034770,40.730010,-74.035290,40.730080,-74.035500,40.730140,-74.035670,40.730200,-74.035800,40.730270,-74.035940,40.730350,-74.036070,40.730380,-74.036120,40.730450,-74.036210,40.730460,-74.036230,40.730570,-74.036370,40.730710,-74.036500,40.730780,-74.036580,40.730840,-74.036670,40.730910,-74.036780,40.730970,-74.036880,40.731040,-74.037000,40.731100,-74.037100,40.731150,-74.037210,40.731220,-74.037360,40.731320,-74.037580,40.731340,-74.037630,40.731360,-74.037680,40.731380,-74.037740,40.731390,-74.037800,40.731540,-74.039420,40.731560,-74.039510,40.731580,-74.039710,40.731600,-74.039940,40.731700,-74.041100,40.731810,-74.042300,40.731850,-74.042760,40.731870,-74.042990,40.731910,-74.043400,40.731940,-74.043670,40.731970,-74.043980,40.731990,-74.044160,40.732010,-74.044420,40.732030,-74.044570,40.732040,-74.044720,40.732040,-74.044880,40.732050,-74.045030,40.732050,-74.045180,40.732040,-74.045340,40.732030,-74.045480,40.732020,-74.045620,40.732000,-74.045760,40.731970,-74.045990,40.731960,-74.046090,40.731960,-74.046090,40.731910,-74.046430,40.731880,-74.046650,40.731810,-74.047300,40.731740,-74.047820,40.731650,-74.048410,40.731620,-74.048560,40.731590,-74.048730,40.731360,-74.049980,40.731360,-74.049980,40.731290,-74.050150,40.731270,-74.050200,40.731250,-74.050230,40.731230,-74.050330,40.731220,-74.050440,40.731210,-74.050550,40.731200,-74.050650,40.731200,-74.050770,40.731190,-74.050860,40.731200,-74.050940,40.731200,-74.051050,40.731210,-74.051160,40.731220,-74.051250,40.731230,-74.051340,40.731240,-74.051420,40.731260,-74.051490,40.731270,-74.051560,40.731290,-74.051630,40.731310,-74.051700,40.731340,-74.051800,40.731370,-74.051860,40.731400,-74.051950,40.731450,-74.052060,40.731490,-74.052160,40.731540,-74.052240,40.731580,-74.052310,40.731630,-74.052380,40.731710,-74.052500,40.731790,-74.052680,40.731890,-74.052780,40.731980,-74.052870,40.732480,-74.053450,40.733440,-74.054550,40.734440,-74.055700,40.735190,-74.056570,40.737140,-74.058820,40.737860,-74.059640,40.737930,-74.059730,40.737980,-74.059790,40.738090,-74.059950,40.738200,-74.060110,40.738290,-74.060260,40.738360,-74.060390,40.738370,-74.060430,40.738430,-74.060530,40.738470,-74.060630,40.738530,-74.060740,40.738590,-74.060880,40.738650,-74.061000,40.738670,-74.061040,40.738720,-74.061160,40.738770,-74.061280,40.738820,-74.061410,40.738880,-74.061560,40.738920,-74.061690,40.738970,-74.061840,40.739000,-74.061920,40.739020,-74.062010,40.739080,-74.062240,40.739080,-74.062260,40.739100,-74.062360,40.739110,-74.062370,40.739200,-74.062790,40.739290,-74.063340,40.739320,-74.064290,40.739340,-74.064650,40.739320,-74.064660,40.739310,-74.064680,40.739310,-74.064690,40.739310,-74.064700,40.739300,-74.064760,40.739300,-74.064830,40.739300,-74.064840,40.739290,-74.064920,40.739290,-74.064930,40.739280,-74.065360,40.739260,-74.065770,40.739250,-74.066090,40.739180,-74.067220,40.739170,-74.067460,40.739160,-74.067610,40.739120,-74.068440,40.739120,-74.068440,40.739090,-74.069190,40.739070,-74.069560,40.739060,-74.069820,40.739030,-74.070420,40.739010,-74.070670,40.739000,-74.070900,40.738980,-74.071080,40.738970,-74.071300,40.738950,-74.071470,40.738910,-74.071730,40.738880,-74.071960,40.738830,-74.072300,40.738770,-74.072670,40.738570,-74.073800,40.738540,-74.073960,40.738540,-74.073970,40.738460,-74.074400,40.738430,-74.074560,40.738360,-74.074930,40.738350,-74.074980,40.738310,-74.075160,40.738260,-74.075410,40.738260,-74.075420,40.738240,-74.075540,40.738220,-74.075600,40.738210,-74.075680,40.738140,-74.076030,40.738040,-74.076550,40.737950,-74.077020,40.737820,-74.077690,40.737790,-74.077870,40.737700,-74.078330,40.737680,-74.078460,40.737660,-74.078710,40.737470,-74.079660,40.737300,-74.080530,40.737150,-74.081330,40.737020,-74.081990,40.736950,-74.082550,40.736770,-74.083610,40.736550,-74.084760,40.736440,-74.085240,40.736390,-74.085460,40.736200,-74.086390,40.735650,-74.089390,40.735450,-74.090820,40.735360,-74.091750,40.735230,-74.093790,40.735150,-74.094670,40.735030,-74.095900,40.734940,-74.097020,40.734860,-74.097820,40.734710,-74.099750,40.734680,-74.100080,40.734660,-74.100270,40.734660,-74.100520,40.734650,-74.101200,40.734640,-74.101460,40.734620,-74.102070,40.734620,-74.102080,40.734620,-74.102090,40.734620,-74.102250,40.734610,-74.102640,40.734580,-74.104510,40.734570,-74.104710,40.734570,-74.104860,40.734570,-74.104890,40.734570,-74.104930,40.734570,-74.105130,40.734570,-74.105440,40.734570,-74.105710,40.734590,-74.106450,40.734610,-74.106740,40.734610,-74.106830,40.734610,-74.106880,40.734620,-74.107180,40.734640,-74.107610,40.734650,-74.107750,40.734660,-74.108010,40.734660,-74.108050,40.734690,-74.108780,40.734710,-74.109440,40.734710,-74.109450,40.734720,-74.109620,40.734790,-74.111330,40.734820,-74.112180,40.734830,-74.112510,40.734830,-74.112530,40.734830,-74.112560,40.734860,-74.113210,40.734890,-74.113960,40.734910,-74.114600,40.734940,-74.115310,40.734970,-74.116090,40.735010,-74.117010,40.735030,-74.117830,40.735060,-74.118360,40.735100,-74.119520,40.735130,-74.120390,40.735160,-74.120930,40.735160,-74.121140,40.735170,-74.121360,40.735170,-74.121660,40.735170,-74.121810,40.735160,-74.121980,40.735160,-74.122090,40.735150,-74.122210,40.735150,-74.122330,40.735140,-74.122460,40.735120,-74.122600,40.735110,-74.122740,40.735100,-74.122870,40.735090,-74.122950,40.735080,-74.123020,40.735050,-74.123220,40.735030,-74.123400,40.735000,-74.123540,40.735000,-74.123560,40.734990,-74.123580,40.734970,-74.123690,40.734970,-74.123720,40.734960,-74.123770,40.734930,-74.123900,40.734880,-74.124150,40.734870,-74.124180,40.734860,-74.124210,40.734830,-74.124340,40.734830,-74.124350,40.734800,-74.124440,40.734800,-74.124450,40.734690,-74.124840,40.734690,-74.124840,40.734680,-74.124870,40.734660,-74.125040,40.734650,-74.125130,40.734650,-74.125200,40.734650,-74.125260,40.734650,-74.125370,40.734650,-74.125480,40.734660,-74.125550,40.734680,-74.125690,40.734710,-74.125860,40.734750,-74.126020,40.734780,-74.126120,40.734780,-74.126150,40.734790,-74.126170,40.734800,-74.126240,40.734810,-74.126270,40.734820,-74.126330,40.734840,-74.126420,40.734860,-74.126490,40.734870,-74.126560,40.734890,-74.126640,40.734900,-74.126720,40.734910,-74.126810,40.734920,-74.126900,40.734930,-74.126980,40.734940,-74.127070,40.734950,-74.127160,40.734960,-74.127250,40.734960,-74.127310,40.734970,-74.127380,40.734970,-74.127450,40.734970,-74.127510,40.734970,-74.127640,40.734970,-74.127780,40.734950,-74.128310,40.734940,-74.128380,40.734940,-74.128410,40.734940,-74.128460,40.734900,-74.129180,40.734780,-74.132380,40.734770,-74.132460,40.734750,-74.132540,40.734740,-74.132590,40.734730,-74.132640,40.734710,-74.132700,40.734690,-74.132760,40.734660,-74.132830,40.734640,-74.132890,40.734610,-74.132950,40.734590,-74.132990,40.734550,-74.133040,40.734520,-74.133090,40.734480,-74.133150,40.734420,-74.133220,40.734360,-74.133290,40.734180,-74.133510,40.734180,-74.133510,40.734150,-74.134250,40.734040,-74.136610,40.734040,-74.136650,40.734030,-74.137080,40.733960,-74.138610,40.733940,-74.139140,40.733940,-74.139340,40.733920,-74.139820,40.733920,-74.139860,40.733870,-74.140800,40.733840,-74.141460,40.733820,-74.141920,40.733780,-74.142650,40.733770,-74.142920,40.733750,-74.143540,40.733730,-74.143810,40.733710,-74.144440,40.733690,-74.144870,40.733670,-74.145320,40.733660,-74.145490,40.733660,-74.145520,40.733610,-74.145720,40.733490,-74.146120,40.733400,-74.146400,40.733260,-74.146950,40.733160,-74.147290,40.733000,-74.147850,40.732910,-74.148170,40.732860,-74.148310,40.732750,-74.148730,40.732730,-74.148830,40.732720,-74.148910,40.732720,-74.149000,40.732730,-74.149080,40.732700,-74.149860,40.732690,-74.150260,40.732710,-74.152170,40.732720,-74.152520,40.732720,-74.153410,40.732720,-74.154010,40.732720,-74.154100,40.732720,-74.155040,40.732720,-74.155190,40.732720,-74.155240,40.732710,-74.155260,40.732710,-74.155280,40.732710,-74.155690,40.732680,-74.156740,40.732670,-74.157230,40.732680,-74.157480,40.732670,-74.157690,40.732690,-74.158220,40.732710,-74.158570,40.732770,-74.158970,40.732830,-74.159310,40.732900,-74.159620,40.732960,-74.159970,40.733050,-74.160350,40.733080,-74.160530,40.733180,-74.160920,40.733180,-74.160920,40.733160,-74.161140,40.733140,-74.161240,40.733140,-74.161310,40.733150,-74.161370,40.733150,-74.161410,40.733160,-74.161460,40.733170,-74.161500,40.733190,-74.161540,40.733210,-74.161580,40.733240,-74.161740,40.733240,-74.161760,40.733240,-74.161780,40.733250,-74.161790,40.733250,-74.161820,40.733240,-74.161890,40.733290,-74.162120,40.733480,-74.162940,40.733690,-74.163770,40.733740,-74.163980,40.733770,-74.164130,40.733840,-74.164480,40.733940,-74.164920,40.734050,-74.165420,40.734080,-74.165540,40.734130,-74.165790,40.734140,-74.165840,40.734150,-74.165880,40.734160,-74.165960,40.734170,-74.166000,40.734260,-74.166450,40.734540,-74.167850,40.734590,-74.168090,40.734670,-74.168530,40.734740,-74.168920,40.734820,-74.169290,40.734850,-74.169520,40.734880,-74.169690,40.734940,-74.169930,40.735160,-74.170720,40.735500,-74.171870,40.735530,-74.171970,40.735550,-74.172050,40.735600,-74.172190,40.735650,-74.172370
38.9847,-77.09429,38.98442,-77.09424,38.98435,-77.09422,38.98426,-77.09419,38.9841,-77.09413,38.98372,-77.09398,38.9836,-77.09393,38.98324,-77.09378,38.98303,-77.09368,38.98267,-77.09349,38.98262,-77.09347,38.98261,-77.09346,38.9825,-77.09341,38.98221,-77.09328,38.98186,-77.09312,38.98132,-77.09285,38.98105,-77.09273,38.98062,-77.0925,38.98004,-77.0922,38.97925,-77.09182,38.97881,-77.09159,38.97847,-77.09141,38.97835,-77.09136,38.97775,-77.09107,38.97753,-77.09095,38.97723,-77.09081,38.97713,-77.09075,38.97656,-77.09047,38.97639,-77.09039,38.97584,-77.09024,38.97568,-77.0902,38.97547,-77.09015,38.97458,-77.08997,38.97365,-77.08979,38.97356,-77.08978,38.97283,-77.08967,38.97221,-77.08958,38.97131,-77.08943,38.97049,-77.0893,38.96957,-77.08917,38.96853,-77.08899,38.9684,-77.08897,38.9676,-77.08883,38.96738,-77.08877,38.96722,-77.08874,38.96692,-77.08866,38.96667,-77.08859,38.96623,-77.08844,38.96617,-77.08842,38.96599,-77.08834,38.96545,-77.0881,38.96537,-77.08805,38.96459,-77.08768,38.96447,-77.08762,38.96437,-77.08758,38.96377,-77.08729,38.9634,-77.0871,38.96277,-77.08677,38.96246,-77.08659,38.96192,-77.08632,38.96158,-77.08615,38.96149,-77.08611,38.96075,-77.0858,38.9607,-77.08569,38.96063,-77.08566,38.96015,-77.08541,38.96009,-77.08538,38.95974,-77.0852,38.9597,-77.08518,38.95964,-77.08515,38.95952,-77.0851,38.95949,-77.08508,38.95941,-77.08504,38.95904,-77.08485,38.95803,-77.08433,38.95712,-77.08387,38.95702,-77.08382,38.95617,-77.08338,38.95595,-77.08327,38.95531,-77.08294,38.9547,-77.08263,38.95461,-77.08259,38.95382,-77.08218,38.9534,-77.08197,38.95332,-77.08194,38.95323,-77.08188,38.95293,-77.08173,38.95252,-77.08152,38.95207,-77.08128,38.95147,-77.08097,38.95114,-77.0808,38.95111,-77.08079,38.95105,-77.08077,38.95088,-77.0807,38.9508,-77.08067,38.95071,-77.08064,38.9506,-77.08061,38.95048,-77.08058,38.95021,-77.08052,38.94988,-77.08041,38.9498,-77.0804,38.94975,-77.08039,38.94968,-77.08039,38.94927,-77.0803,38.94914,-77.08027,38.94887,-77.0802,38.94878,-77.08017,38.94875,-77.08016,38.94871,-77.08015,38.94863,-77.0801,38.94848,-77.08001,38.94842,-77.07997,38.94835,-77.07994,38.94807,-77.07977,38.94793,-77.07968,38.94774,-77.07957,38.94755,-77.07947,38.94747,-77.07943,38.94708,-77.07921,38.94688,-77.0791,38.94651,-77.0789,38.94651,-77.0789,38.94649,-77.07894,38.94646,-77.07897,38.94643,-77.07901,38.94641,-77.07903,38.94637,-77.07906,38.94634,-77.07908,38.94632,-77.0791,38.9463,-77.07911,38.94628,-77.07912,38.94625,-77.07913,38.94622,-77.07913,38.94619,-77.07913,38.94615,-77.07913,38.94611,-77.07912,38.94611,-77.07912,38.94603,-77.07913,38.94599,-77.07913,38.94595,-77.07914,38.94591,-77.07915,38.94588,-77.07916,38.94585,-77.07918,38.94582,-77.0792,38.94565,-77.0793,38.94562,-77.07932,38.94519,-77.07969,38.9451,-77.07981,38.9448,-77.08006,38.9447,-77.08014,38.94456,-77.08025,38.94435,-77.08041,38.94422,-77.08052,38.94367,-77.081,38.94348,-77.08116,38.94335,-77.08127,38.94318,-77.08141,38.9429,-77.08164,38.94288,-77.08166,38.94252,-77.08197,38.9424,-77.08207,38.94232,-77.08214,38.9422,-77.08224,38.94199,-77.08242,38.9418,-77.0826,38.94153,-77.08282,38.94142,-77.08292,38.94131,-77.08302,38.9412,-77.08311,38.94087,-77.08338,38.9408,-77.08345,38.94069,-77.08355,38.94035,-77.08385,38.9402,-77.08398,38.93996,-77.08418,38.93967,-77.08442,38.93932,-77.08471,38.9389,-77.08509,38.93883,-77.08514,38.93883,-77.08515,38.93876,-77.0852,38.93872,-77.08524,38.9385,-77.0854,38.9384,-77.08553,38.93838,-77.08556,38.93835,-77.0856,38.93833,-77.08563,38.9383,-77.08567,38.93827,-77.08573,38.93827,-77.08573,38.93828,-77.08577,38.93828,-77.08579,38.93828,-77.08579,38.93828,-77.08587,38.93828,-77.08591,38.93827,-77.08598,38.93826,-77.08603,38.93825,-77.08607,38.93824,-77.08611,38.93822,-77.08614,38.93821,-77.08616,38.9382,-77.08618,38.93819,-77.0862,38.93817,-77.08622,38.93816,-77.08624,38.93814,-77.08625,38.93813,-77.08626,38.93812,-77.08628,38.93809,-77.0863,38.93805,-77.08633,38.938,-77.08636,38.93797,-77.08637,38.93794,-77.08638,38.93791,-77.08639,38.93791,-77.08639,38.93788,-77.08639,38.93783,-77.08638,38.9378,-77.08636,38.93775,-77.08634,38.93772,-77.08632,38.93769,-77.0863,38.93764,-77.08627,38.93757,-77.08608,38.93757,-77.08608,38.93757,-77.08605,38.93756,-77.08602,38.93755,-77.08598,38.93755,-77.08598,38.93755,-77.08594,38.93754,-77.08589,38.93753,-77.08584,38.93753,-77.0858,38.93753,-77.08576,38.93753,-77.08571,38.93753,-77.08566,38.93753,-77.08562,38.93753,-77.08558,38.93752,-77.08554,38.93751,-77.08549,38.93749,-77.08543,38.93747,-77.08538,38.93745,-77.08534,38.93743,-77.0853,38.9374,-77.08525,38.93732,-77.08508,38.93704,-77.08472,38.93698,-77.08464,38.93697,-77.08462,38.93688,-77.08451,38.93674,-77.08431,38.93671,-77.08427,38.93669,-77.08424,38.93656,-77.08407,38.93645,-77.08392,38.93626,-77.08366,38.93608,-77.08341,38.93607,-77.08339,38.93565,-77.08282,38.93511,-77.08207,38.9351,-77.08206,38.93496,-77.08188,38.93471,-77.08154,38.93462,-77.08142,38.93415,-77.0808,38.934,-77.08058,38.93377,-77.08026,38.93355,-77.07994,38.93352,-77.0799,38.93344,-77.07978,38.93286,-77.079,38.93278,-77.07888,38.93253,-77.07854,38.93208,-77.07791,38.93196,-77.07776,38.93173,-77.07744,38.9315,-77.07712,38.93147,-77.07708,38.93146,-77.07707,38.9314,-77.07701,38.93131,-77.07687,38.93093,-77.07635,38.93018,-77.07534,38.92988,-77.07492,38.92975,-77.07473,38.92965,-77.0746,38.92932,-77.07413,38.92912,-77.07386,38.9291,-77.07383,38.92902,-77.07372,38.92891,-77.07358,38.92886,-77.07352,38.92876,-77.07338,38.92873,-77.07334,38.92861,-77.07318,38.92828,-77.07273,38.92777,-77.07201,38.92753,-77.07167,38.92744,-77.07155,38.92713,-77.07114,38.92695,-77.07089,38.92639,-77.07013,38.92617,-77.06984,38.92607,-77.0697,38.92585,-77.06939,38.92561,-77.06907,38.92534,-77.06869,38.92476,-77.06789,38.92471,-77.06783,38.92468,-77.06777,38.92464,-77.06771,38.92461,-77.06765,38.92459,-77.06761,38.92457,-77.06757,38.92454,-77.06751,38.92451,-77.06744,38.92449,-77.06737,38.92447,-77.06732,38.92445,-77.06726,38.92443,-77.0672,38.92441,-77.06714,38.9244,-77.06707,38.92439,-77.06702,38.92438,-77.06697,38.92437,-77.06692,38.92436,-77.06684,38.9243,-77.06661,38.92429,-77.06651,38.92428,-77.06636,38.92426,-77.06623,38.92424,-77.06614,38.92422,-77.06604,38.9242,-77.06594,38.92417,-77.06584,38.92415,-77.06575,38.92412,-77.06566,38.92409,-77.06556,38.92406,-77.06547,38.92401,-77.06535,38.92396,-77.06524,38.92393,-77.06516,38.92389,-77.06509,38.92385,-77.065,38.9238,-77.06492,38.92376,-77.06484,38.92371,-77.06475,38.92366,-77.06467,38.92362,-77.0646,38.92358,-77.06455,38.92352,-77.06447,38.92347,-77.0644,38.9234,-77.06433,38.92335,-77.06426,38.9233,-77.0642,38.92324,-77.06414,38.92318,-77.06408,38.9231,-77.06401,38.92305,-77.06396,38.92299,-77.06391,38.92293,-77.06386,38.92287,-77.06382,38.9228,-77.06376,38.92272,-77.06372,38.92264,-77.06367,38.92257,-77.06362,38.92249,-77.06358,38.9224,-77.06354,38.92233,-77.06351,38.92227,-77.06348,38.92219,-77.06345,38.92213,-77.06343,38.92206,-77.06341,38.92201,-77.0634,38.92195,-77.06338,38.92189,-77.06337,38.92183,-77.06336,38.92177,-77.06334,38.92172,-77.06333,38.92166,-77.06331,38.92159,-77.06328,38.92153,-77.06326,38.92146,-77.06321,38.9214,-77.06317,38.92134,-77.06314,38.92128,-77.0631,38.92121,-77.06297,38.92117,-77.06294,38.92112,-77.06288,38.92108,-77.06284,38.92104,-77.06279,38.92099,-77.06273,38.92091,-77.06262,38.91865,-77.05954,38.91847,-77.05929,38.91841,-77.0592,38.91837,-77.05914,38.91833,-77.05909,38.91831,-77.05905,38.91827,-77.05901,38.9182,-77.05892,38.91803,-77.05869,38.91779,-77.05839,38.91745,-77.05791,38.91709,-77.0574,38.91705,-77.05736,38.91703,-77.05732,38.91662,-77.05677,38.91551,-77.05525,38.91404,-77.05324,38.91362,-77.05266,38.91329,-77.05221,38.91271,-77.05142,38.91259,-77.05132,38.91252,-77.05123,38.9125,-77.0512,38.91248,-77.05117,38.91245,-77.05114,38.91243,-77.05112,38.9124,-77.05109,38.91237,-77.05107,38.91234,-77.05106,38.9123,-77.05105,38.91227,-77.05105,38.91225,-77.05105,38.91225,-77.05105,38.9122,-77.05104,38.91216,-77.05104,38.91212,-77.05104,38.91209,-77.05103,38.91206,-77.05102,38.91204,-77.05101,38.91201,-77.051,38.91199,-77.05098,38.91197,-77.05096,38.91194,-77.05093,38.91193,-77.05091,38.9119,-77.05088,38.91188,-77.05084,38.91187,-77.0508,38.91186,-77.05075,38.91185,-77.05072,38.91185,-77.0507,38.91185,-77.05066,38.91185,-77.05061,38.91186,-77.05056,38.91188,-77.0505,38.91189,-77.05046,38.91191,-77.05042,38.91191,-77.05039,38.91192,-77.05036,38.91193,-77.05033,38.91193,-77.05028,38.91194,-77.05022,38.91194,-77.05018,38.91193,-77.05013,38.91192,-77.05009,38.91191,-77.05005,38.91186,-77.04993,38.91181,-77.04969,38.91158,-77.049,38.91151,-77.04881,38.91147,-77.04869,38.91112,-77.0477,38.91075,-77.04663,38.91054,-77.04601,38.91043,-77.0457,38.91014,-77.04488,38.91009,-77.04473,38.90995,-77.04447,38.90991,-77.04435,38.90989,-77.04432,38.90987,-77.04429,38.90985,-77.04426,38.90979,-77.04421,38.90976,-77.04418,38.90973,-77.04416,38.90971,-77.04415,38.90969,-77.04414,38.90966,-77.04414,38.90963,-77.04413,38.90963,-77.04413,38.9096,-77.04413,38.90955,-77.04411,38.90952,-77.0441,38.90949,-77.04409,38.90946,-77.04407,38.90943,-77.04406,38.9094,-77.04404,38.90937,-77.04402,38.90934,-77.04399,38.90932,-77.04397,38.90929,-77.04394,38.90926,-77.04391,38.90924,-77.04387,38.90921,-77.04384,38.9092,-77.04381,38.90918,-77.04378,38.90917,-77.04374,38.90915,-77.04369,38.90914,-77.04364,38.90913,-77.04359,38.90912,-77.04355,38.90911,-77.0435,38.90911,-77.04345,38.90911,-77.0434,38.90912,-77.04335,38.90912,-77.04331,38.90913,-77.04327,38.90915,-77.04322,38.90917,-77.04315,38.90918,-77.0431,38.9092,-77.04306,38.90923,-77.04302,38.90925,-77.04298,38.90927,-77.04295,38.90928,-77.04292,38.90929,-77.04289,38.9093,-77.04286,38.90931,-77.04282,38.9093,-77.04278,38.9093,-77.04278,38.90931,-77.04265,38.90931,-77.04261,38.90931,-77.04258,38.90931,-77.04256,38.9093,-77.04253,38.90925,-77.04239,38.90919,-77.04212,38.90904,-77.0417,38.90852,-77.04021,38.90843,-77.03995,38.90826,-77.03946,38.90818,-77.03923,38.90812,-77.03906,38.90801,-77.03875,38.90793,-77.0385,38.90773,-77.03792,38.90763,-77.03765,38.90762,-77.03762,38.90754,-77.03741,38.90747,-77.03735,38.90731,-77.03709,38.90726,-77.03698,38.90726,-77.03698,38.90723,-77.03699,38.90716,-77.03691
```