# video is not loading, what is wrong in the code

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function t() {
  var u = document.getElementById("fileupload").value;
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  document.getElementById.scr = u;
  video.load();
  video.play();
};
```

```html
<button id="submit" value="submit" onclick="t();">play</button>
<embed id="video" width="330" height="220" scr="">
```

Comment: There's no *element* with Id `"fileupload"` in the code you show.

Comment: Are you sure this `document.getElementById.scr = u` is correct?

Comment: <input type="file" name="fileupload" value="fileupload" id="fileupload">
<label for="fileupload"> Select a file to play</label>

Comment: @marekful indeed, seems like it should be `src` instead of `scr`.

Comment: i have used this

Comment: i have changed scr to src even it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You cannot able to directly read or play video using its src or id.

You have to do something like below to complete your requirements.
Use `FileReader` function to read file source from `input type file`

```
<script>
    function t() {
      var preview = document.querySelector('embed');
      var video   = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
      var reader  = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function () {
        preview.src = reader.result;
      }

      if (video) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(video);
      } else {
        preview.src = "";
      }

      //video.load();
      //video.play();
    };
</script>

<input type="file" name="fileupload" value="fileupload" id="fileupload"> 
<label for="fileupload"> Select a file to play</label>

<embed id="video" width="330" height="220" scr="">
<button id="submit" value="submit" onclick="t();">play</button>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jh0mgfev/7/)

Comment: thank for your reply, even it is not working can you give some other way to play video

Comment: thanks for your reply, still i am facing the same issue. I am not able to play the video.

Comment: what is issue is i am able to play video in firefox, but its displays error in ie and chrome

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100927/chrome-filereader this may help to work the code in chrome or IE